# API won't return data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to call API when I'm in the page that show data for the specific Profile.

The url looks like: `localhost:8000/profile/223`

API also require to be called `api/profile/223`

The way that I'm trying to call the API is:

```
const ProfileLayout = () => {
    const [profileId, setProfileId] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('api/profile/id')
        .then(result => {
            setProfileId(result.id);
        });
    }, [id])
    };
```

Comment: put a "/" in front of the URL... `/api/profile/${id}`, otherwise, you're making a request to "localhost:8000/profile/223/api/profile/223"

Comment: what is the error message

Comment: The error is 404 Method Not Allowed

Answer (score 2):

Fetch requires you to return the format of data from the Response object before you can use the data. Use [`response.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) to get the JSON from your request.

And like @Adriana6 mentioned, add the `/` to the start of your URL.

Use the `profileId` to inject the value into the URL string.

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch('/api/profile/${profileId}')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
      setProfileId(result.id);
    });
}, []);
```

I don't have a lot of experience in React.js but learned how to do this by [reading this article](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data) on how to make `fetch` requests with React Hooks. I suggest that you look into it as well.

Comment: I'm getting the ID as undefined. The API is not called because it require maybe the ID that is in URL

Answer (score 1):

Please write the full url like `localhost:8000/profile/${id}` in your fetch function parameter. Then parse it as json.

On the other hand, you don't have any id field. So, using id in you useEffect will not be triggered at all. If you want it to be triggered on page load then use

```
useEffect(() => {
    // fetch
}, [])
```

instead of

```
useEffect(() => {
    // fetch
}, [id])
```

Or you can change `id` with `profileId`. In that case, you have to check if `profileId` is truthy (not null) before fetchin profile data